# Why are user account on remote server called shell account

Tags: linux, shell, networking, history

Why are user accounts on a remote server called `shell account` , `remote account` sounds like a more intuitive name

what is the reason behind this very unintuitive name ???

Comment: Because you login to a shell on the remote machine...

Answer (score 3):

The term 'remote account' doesn't tell me anything about the nature of the account.  I know it is on a remote machine, but that is about it.

Could it be for email? for printing? for mysql management? is it an RDP login?  a samba share?

You see, remote is not descriptive or intuitive at all.  The term `shell` refers to the command interpreter you use when you login to a unix or linux machine via a TTY or open a terminal from X, or remotely via telnet or ssh.

Examples of shells:

- `sh` - Bourne shell
- `bash` - the Bourne again shell
- `ksh` - Korn shell
- `csh` - C shell
- `zsh` - Z shell
- `pdksh` - public domain Korn shell
- `ash` - Almquist shell
- `dash` - Debian Almquist shell

The `sh` in each of these programs names stands for `shell`.  So, if I have a unix account that grants me access to a shell, the most descriptive, intuitive name I can come up with is shell account.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Wikipedia page on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_account):

> **shell account** - A shell account is a user account on a remote server, traditionally running under the Unix operating system, which gives access to a shell via a command-line interface protocol such as telnet or SSH. ...

So the fact that it utilizes a "shell" such as Bash, Bourne, etc. is why.